# List item when its clicked downloads a file from the internet?

Tags: android

Hey guys I'm trying to make a simple ROM list app and i was wondering how to downloaded a file when I list item is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the [`ListView`-tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) on how to react on a `ListItem`-click (and tell which one was clicked).

On how to download files from the Internet have a look at those classes:

- [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)
- [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)
- [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)
- And depending on what your response is, the right [Reader-Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html).

Comment: ty for answer and I'm sorry that this isn't a complete question :/